# Expect 'send' not working as expected

Tags: send, expect

I am a beginner in expect...I have written a small script which has to login to a router and execute few commands..
But somehow i am finding that even though when i have used send "admin show platform" THRICE, it is only working twice for me.. I only get the output of `admin show platform` twice.

Can anyone check the code and point me where actually i am screwing up the code..

```
Gsaxena# 
Gsaxena# 
Gsaxena# ./testTool  
spawn /usr/bin/ksh  
telnet 5.28.7.103  
$ telnet 5.28.7.103  
Trying 5.28.7.103...   
Connected to 5.28.7.103.  
Escape character is '^]'.  


User Access Verification   

Username:   
Username: lab  
Password:   


RP/0/RP0/CPU0:Billorani#debug ospf ospf1 adj  
Mon Oct 14 17:16:06.144 UTC  
**RP/0/RP0/CPU0:Billorani#show platform**  
Mon Oct 14 17:16:06.416 UTC  
Node          Type              PLIM               State           Config State  
------------- ----------------- ------------------ --------------- ---------------  
x/x/x0      xxxxG          N/A                IN-RESET        PWR,NSHUT,MON  

**RP/0/RP0/CPU0:Billorani#show platform**  
Mon Oct 14 17:16:06.416 UTC  
Node          Type              PLIM               State           Config State  
------------- ----------------- ------------------ --------------- ---------------  
x/x/xxx0      xxxxG          N/A                IN-RESET        PWR,NSHUT,MON  
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:Billorani#  

Gsaxena#   
Gsaxena#   
Gsaxena#   
Gsaxena#   
Gsaxena#   


#!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 30
    set hostcut "Bil"
        sleep 5
        set timeout 5

        spawn /usr/bin/ksh
        send "telnet 5.8.7.103\r"
        expect ".*\'\^\]\'\. *"
        send "\r"
        expect "Username\:"
        send "lab\n"
        expect "Password\: "
        send "lab\n"
        sleep 10

        expect -re "RP\/.\/.*\/CPU.:$hostcut.*#"
        send "debug ospf ospf1 adj\n"

        expect -re "RP\/.\/.*\/CPU.:$hostcut.*#"
        send "admin show platform\n"

        expect -re "RP\/.\/.*\/CPU.:$hostcut.*#"
        send "admin show platform\n"

        expect -re "RP\/.\/.*\/CPU.:$hostcut.*#"
        send "admin show platform\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

I should really be placing this not in an actual answer but in a comment, since I do not have a final answer for you, but it seems comments can only be left by folks who have been around for some time (there's a minimum reputation before you can leave them).

Anyways, what I wanted to suggest was that you add `exp_internal 1` somewhere near the start of your script. This will provide a ton of useful debugging information, and will most likely point at what is going on. Feel free to post it here if you need help with it.

I can't tell what is wrong from the information you posted... nothing seems obviously at fault. One thing I would do differently is instead of spawning a Korn shell process and then send a telnet commando to it, I would just spawn the telnet command directly (less code, less resources). But that is not what is bothering you, so never mind that.

I'm not familiar with the OS you're logging in to... is that Cisco IOS XR? I'm baffled by the fact that you issue an `admin show platform` command, yet only `show platform` shows in your stdout? Also, what's the deal with the dual asterisks (**) some prompts show, while others don't?

One last thing, which may seem dumb, but... can you manually access the device and issue those 4 exact commands, in that exact order?

Regards,
James

Comment: Thanks James.. I tried with the exp_internal 1 option but because i am kinda very new to expect, i didnt understand much the logs generated by 'exp_internal 1'.. Yes i am using Cisco IOS XR. 'admin show platform' command actually go to router's admin mode and execute the 'sh platform'...Regarding (**) i am not sure why this is shown in my query above...In router this symbol is not show . It might be due to formatting in stackoverflow...anyways this ** is not part of the output.

Comment: Hmm... I see. That dual asterisk thing is pretty weird. Anyways, if you want to edit your question to include the `exp_internal 1` output, I'll be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
send "admin show platform\n"
```

Use "\r" instead of "\n"